# How to get zsh to not save commands that have failed into history?

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history

I would like to have zsh not save commands that have failed into the history file. The reason for this is to have a tidier output when I am searching through previous commands later on. I don't want to save my mistyp

Comment: Is this relevant ? https://superuser.com/questions/902241/how-to-make-zsh-not-store-failed-command